# What is the difference between the members on home page vs members in the site permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, administration, groups

On the SharePoint site home page, at the top right, just below the settings (gear) icon I can see the following text: `3 members`. When I click on this I can see 3 users: myself with Owner permissions, and 2 colleagues with Member permission.

When I click on the setting icon and go to the site permissions, then expand the site owners, members, visitors, I don't see my 2 colleagues listed there. I also clicked on advanced permission settings and checked the permissions and group memberships but those 2 colleagues of mine don't show up here.

What is the difference between the members on home page vs members in the site permissions?

Comment: Are you using team site connected with M365 groups?

Comment: My admin has created this for me. I know that it is a teams site. But unsure if connected to M365 group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using SharePoint online team site connected with Microsoft 365 groups.

The groups you see directly from site home page are M365 groups.

And the groups you see under site permissions page are SharePoint groups.

By default "M365 Members" group is added inside the "SharePoint Members" group in team sites:

- The M365 group's Owners will be the site collection administrators
- The M365 group's Owners are added to your site's Owners group (hidden by default)
- The M365 group's Members are added to your site's Members group

When you add users in the M365 members/owners group, those does not show up inside the SharePoint members/owners group directly as the permissions are handled using M365 groups (added inside the SharePoint groups).

---

Check below Microsoft official documentations to understand the connection between SharePoint sites and M365 groups:

1. [SharePoint and Microsoft 365 Groups integration (IT Admins)](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/solutions/groups-sharepoint-governance?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Sharing and permissions in the SharePoint modern experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Microsoft Teams, SharePoint, and Microsoft 365 Groups integration (IT Admins)](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/solutions/groups-sharepoint-teams-governance?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: can we create SharePoint site without M365 group? What is the use case of this?

Comment: Yes, you can. Check: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/sharepoint-online-create-modern-site-without-group.html

Comment: What is the use case when we should have a M365 group and when should we not have this integration?

Comment: Check the links given above once. M365 group comes with SharePoint site, team in Microsoft teams, Planner, Outlook group, Group calendar, etc. So, if you need collaboration across all these M365 resources, you can use the M365 group.